Cluster Master node cannot find other nodes
I have a CentOS cluster (version 7) with a few nodes. The problem is that the master node is not recognizing their nodes.
I am using slurm 18.08.8. I use sbatch command to run my program, but I get the following error:
Nodes required for job are DOWN, DRAINED or reserved for jobs in higher priority partitions

This problem started when the cluster was suddenly shut down due to a power outage.

This looks like you are using slurm as the resource manager. Can you confirm this by editing your question and giving the version of slurm you're using? Have you browsed the slurm FAQ?

@doneal24 Thanks for your comments. I am using slurm 18.08.8. This system worked fine. But the system was turned down suddenly because of the electricity power and now the master node is not recognizing others.

Please consider accepting my answer if it meets your needs.

The master node is recognizing the other nodes in the cluster but, since they were shut down outside of slurm, the slurm controller cannot know that they are now functional. For each node in the cluster, run
scontrol: update NodeName=cnxx State=DOWN Reason="undraining"
scontrol: update NodeName=cnxx State=RESUME

where cnxx is the name of the node. You can use the standard node ranges if appropriate. btw, slurm 18.x has been unsupported for 6+ years and CentOS 7 is also EOL.

I used above command and get the following error:
\
Error: A valid LosF config directory was not detected. You must provide a valid config
path for your local cluster. This can be accomplished via one of two methods:
(1) Add your desired config path to the file -> /opt/ohpc/admin/losf/config/config_dir
(2) Set the LOSF_CONFIG_DIR environment variable
Example configuration files are availabe at -> /opt/ohpc/admin/losf/config/config_example
Note: for new systems, you can also run "initconfig " to create
a starting LosF configuration template.

@Martin I've never used OpenHPC so I can't help you here.

One can see the losf directory contents as: https://github.com/hpcsi/losf/tree/devel/config I modified config_dir.template and added this new directory address :"opt/ohpc/admin/losf/config". But again I get invalid losf directory error during slurm update command. Should I create a Bash file with some commands in the specified directory? Any comments establishing  losf config directory will be highly appreciated.

Sorry @doneal24, I made a foolish mistake on using your answer. I used them without any scontrol command. Interestingly, on using your two comments I got no error in this case. So, I used sinfo command to see the node status. First, the status changed to "unknown" and after several minutes, again it shows "down*" :( ---  Any more comments will be highly appreciated
